# Установить Wordpress рядом с Flask

Tags: wordpress, flask

Сайт сделан на Flask и развернут на хостинге, запускается через wsgi
Как можно установить Wordpress например на адрес example.ru/blog
Если на example.ru стоит flask?
Установка просто в папку не работает

Comment: Зависит от хостинга

Comment: Как зависит? что там должно быть? А если на vds?

Comment: Ну как минимум для wordpress должно быть что-то, что способно запускать php-код, а веб-сервер должен быть способен, получив запрос на /blog, обратиться к этому чему-то для запуска php-кода. Написать что-то более конкретное с нулевой информацией о хостинге/dns не получится, под «что-то» может скрываться много разных вариантов

Comment: Ставишь в папку и подключаешь конфиг апач/nginx на эту папку